# Nested loop in Python with index

Tags: python

I'm trying to create some for loop using this code:

```python
StaticSteps = [2, 3, 1]
RAngles = [85.6,80.5,76]
increement = 50
    
           
for i, StaticStep in enumerate(StaticSteps):
    RAngle = RAngles[i]
    count = 0
    while count < StaticStep:
        print(RAngle, increement)
        print('')
        count = count+1
```

The result that I got is:

```
85.6 50

85.6 50

80.5 50

80.5 50

80.5 50

76 50
```

However, I want to add another loop on the left side so that results become:

```
50 85.6 50

100 85.6 50

150 80.5 50

200 80.5 50

250 80.5 50

300 76 50
```

How could I fix the code?

Comment: Is there any logical relation between the numbers 50..300 you also want printed and the variables in your code?

Comment: i want to start from 50 to 300 with 50 increement. Dont know how to include that into the loop.

Comment: You don't add another loop, you just need another variable.

Comment: What's the point of `count`? Why not just `for _ in range(StaticStep)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a new loop, rather a new variable. You could do as follows:

```python
StaticSteps = [2, 3, 1]
RAngles = [85.6,80.5,76]
increment = 50
newIncrement = increment

for i, StaticStep in enumerate(StaticSteps):
   RAngle = RAngles[i]
   count = 0
   while count < StaticStep:
       print(newIncrement, RAngle, increment)
       print('')
       count = count+1
       newIncrement = newIncrement + increment
```

Here, I have included a new variable `newIncrement` which is printed and incremented by 50 after each iteration.

Output:

```python
>>> 50 85.6 50

100 85.6 50

150 80.5 50

200 80.5 50

250 80.5 50

300 76 50
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cnt = 0
for i, step in enumerate(static_steps):
     for _ in range(step):
          print(f"{(increment*cnt)+increment} {r_angles[i]} {increment}")
          cnt += 1
```

Comment: `(increment*cnt)+increment` is also just `increment*(cnt+1)`